Whitelabel Error on 8080, ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked error on 4200
Angular w/ SpringBoot & SQL backend.
Main page of the site loads, but when I go to 4200/customer or 8080/api/customer it isn't loading. 4200/customer loads the angular, but the back-end fails to load.
BackEnd:
(Customer.java)
package com.example.demo.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customers")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "customer_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    //NOTE: inside sql this is customer_first_name
    @Column(name = "customer_first_name")
    private String firstName;

    //NOTE: inside sql this is customer_last_name
    @Column(name = "customer_last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "postal_code")
    private String postal_code;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "create_date")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date create_date;

    @Column(name = "last_update")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date last_update;

    //NOTE: SQL has a division_id column
    //help with this ???????????????????????????????????????
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name ="division_id")
    private Division division;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)//, mappedBy = "customer")//, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name ="customer_id")
    private Set<Cart> carts;
}



CustomerRepository.java
package com.example.demo.dao;

import com.example.demo.entities.Customer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "customers", path = "customers")
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
}




RestDataConfig.java
package com.example.demo.config;

import com.example.demo.entities.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;

/**

 * TODO restrict non-used rest api end points

@Configuration
public class RestDataConfig implements RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    /**
     * This method exposes standard rest api end points for the following classes:
     * Country
     * Customer
     * Division
     * Excursion
     * Vacation
     * <p>
     * Set page configuration parameters
     *
     * @param config
     * @param cors
     */
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config, CorsRegistry cors) {
        config.exposeIdsFor(Country.class);
        config.exposeIdsFor(Customer.class);
        config.exposeIdsFor(Division.class);
        config.exposeIdsFor(Excursion.class);
        config.exposeIdsFor(Vacation.class);
        config.setDefaultPageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        config.setMaxPageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);


    }
}




SQL Columns for Customer
SELECT `customers`.`customer_id`,
    `customers`.`address`,
    `customers`.`create_date`,
    `customers`.`customer_first_name`,
    `customers`.`customer_last_name`,
    `customers`.`last_update`,
    `customers`.`phone`,
    `customers`.`postal_code`,
    `customers`.`division_id`
FROM `full-stack-ecommerce`.`customers`;


Customer.ts
export class Customer {  
constructor(    
public id: number,    
public address: string,    
public postal_code: string,    
public firstName: string,    
public lastName: string,    
public phone: string,   
public division_id: number,    
public _links?: {     
   self?: {        href : string      },      
   customer?: {        href : string      },      
   division?: {        href : string      },      
   carts?: {        href : string      }    }  ) {  }}

I've tried making small changed to each of the java side of the code. Making sure SQL columns match, and the angular columns match.
I do notice that inside angular, they have "division_id" as a property, but I declare division_id in java as:
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name ="division_id")
private Division division;


There is very likely editing errors due to the transition from IntelliJ to here.

Angular error, no Angular code shared!

I shared the customer.ts file. Which supporting files do you need? This is for a java course, and the angular portion is supposedly correct, so I focused on sharing more back end.

This is just an interface, like a java class, we require the component code, maybe check the stacktrace and share the file from front end where the error occours!

one point to note, this is not a blocking error, you can ignore this and proceed with the java tutorial, its not that serious!

Thank you! I'll try to continue past it then.
